# Cannot post form data to app.js

Tags: html, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I know that similar question has already been asked, but I cannot find anything that works for me.

I am trying to post some HTML form data to my app.js file.

Here is my index.handlebars file:

```
<form method = 'post' action = '/refund'>
  <input type = "text" name = "transId" placeholder = "transID">
  <input type = "text" name = "amount" placeholder = "amount">
<input type = "submit">
```

This posts to the following route:

```
//refund route
app.post('/refund', (req, res, next) => {

console.log(req.body.amount);
console.log(req.body.transId);
```

However, I am getting the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'amount' of undefined`

I have tried every combination of things, and just passing `req.body`, `req.params`, everything is just `undefined`.

Comment: Do you have a bodyparser? -> https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body

Comment: I have tried with the following method:const bodyParse = require('body-parser');

const formParse = bodyParse.raw();                                                                            app.post('/refund', formParse, (req, res, next) => {                                         console.log(req.body.amount);                                                                       Still didn't work

Comment: Have you tried `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` as a middleware? Since you are sending the data from `<form>`.
And one more thing, try providing the full URL, like `//myapp.herokuapp.com/refund` for example to `action` attribute of the `<form>`

Comment: @VladimirJovanović, that worked, thank you!

Comment: Ok, I'll post the answer

Comment: Express comes with a middleware for parsing it. No need to add body-parser to package.json unless you're using an old version of express. Just do this: `app.use(express.urlencoded())` https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html

Answer (score 1):

Add this middleware to your code

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

since you are sending the `form` data.

Also, try providing the full URL path to the route, like `//myapp.herokuapp.com/refund` to `action` **attribute** of the `<form>`.